# Genéricos, estender a uma X ou Y

Tags: java, genéricos

Como faço pra que minha classe genérica só receba tipos que estendam da classe X ou Y?

Exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasseGenerica<T extends ClasseX ou ClasseY>
```

Desculpe se ficou meio confuso, sou novato ainda, não sei explicar muito bem.

Comment: Que tipo de coisas há nas classes X e Y?

Answer (score 3):

Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://onewebsql.com/blog/generics-extends-super).

Java não admite herança múltipla. Uma classe não pode estender duas classes. Você pode estender uma classe e múltiplas interfaces. Por exemplo:

```
public class GenericsTest {

    class Vehicle { }

    interface PassengerVehicle { }
    interface MotorVehicle { }

    // Classe genérica que compila sem problemas
    class ParkingGarage<X extends Vehicle & MotorVehicle & PassengerVehicle>{}


    // Vamos criar uma segunda classe
    class Vehicle2 { }
    // Não compila porque X não pode estender duas classes ao mesmo tempo
    class ParkingGarage2<X extends Vehicle & Vehicle2 >{}
}
```

A solução para o seu problema talvez seja criar uma classe mãe da qual as suas duas classes sejam filhas. Você pode ter uma classe mãe com várias filhas, mas não uma classe filha com várias mães.

Comment: Isto não respone a pergunta. A pergunta foi sobre como restringir as classes aceitas no template, e não sobre herança múltipla.

Comment: "Java não admite herança múltipla, uma classe não pode e**s**tender duas classes" é uma resposta.

Comment: @renan corrigido ;-)

Comment: Exatamente o que o @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira disse...

Answer (score 3):

Isso não é possível, e nem faz sentido.

O motivo é a forma como a `MinhaClasseGenerica` seria usada. Nesta classe, o `T` poderia aparecer como um tipo de retorno de um método, um parâmetro ou o tipo de um campo.

Vamos supor que apareça como o retorno de um método:

```java
public T metodoQualquer() {
    // ...
    return algumObjeto;
}
```

E eu queira usar este método:

```java
public void outroMetodo() {
    T algumObjeto = metodoQualquer();
    // Aqui invoca algum método sobre T.
}
```

Quais são os métodos que o tipo `T` possui? A resposta é que ele **talvez** possa possuir os métodos de `X` e **talvez** possa possuir os métodos de `Y`. Mas, os únicos métodos que sabemos **com certeza** que ele possui serão aqueles que estão tanto em `X` quanto em `Y`.

Ora, neste caso os métodos que estão em `X` mas não em `Y` ou que estão em `Y` mas não em `X`, não podem ser usados sem um *cast*, e o compilador estaria certo em emitir um erro de compilação se você fizesse isso:

```java
public void outroMetodo() {
    T algumObjeto = metodoQualquer();
    algumObjeto.metodoQueSoExisteNoX();
}
```

Afinal, este método pode não existir na referência dada caso `algumObjeto` seja um `Y` ao invés de um `X`. Isso te forçaria a usar um *cast*, mas se você é forçado a usar *casts*, então não tem motivo usar o tipo genérico.

Talvez o que você queira é que `T` possua os métodos de `X` **e** de `Y` ao invés dos métodos de `X` **ou** de `Y`. Neste caso você pode declarar o seguinte:

```java
class MinhaClasseGenerica<T extends X & Y>
```

Por outro lado, talvez `X` e `Y` tenham algo em comum. Neste caso o ideal seria fazer o seguinte:

```java
interface Z {
    // Aqui vai o que há de comum entre X e Y.
}

interface X extends Z {
    // Aqui vai o que há em X, mas não em Y.
}

interface Y extends Z {
    // Aqui vai o que há em Y, mas não em X.
}

class MinhaClasseGenerica<T extends Z> {
    // ...
}
```

Isso daí resolveria o seu problema. Ainda permitiria que eu pudesse inventar um `W` que também herda de `Z` e não é nem `X` e nem `Y`, mas isso é inerente da linguagem: a herança é aberta. Não há herança fechada em Java. Aliás, o fato de não haver herança fechada em Java me permite fazer isso:

```java
// Isso não é Exception e nem Error, mas eu posso dar throw nele!
class WTF extends Throwable {}
```

Se o que você quer é algo fechado, o caminho talvez seja trabalhar com `enums`.

Por fim, vale sempre lembrar que java não tem herança múltipla de classes, e portanto um `<T extends X & Y>` aonde ambos `X` e `Y` são classes é proibido pela linguagem. Pelo menos um dos dois deve ser uma interface.